# How do you wait for an user to click a tkinter button with threads

Tags: python, multithreading, events, tkinter

I am currently working on a projet similar to tic tac toe (with an AI)
And I did a GUI to allow the user to play with the bot
But the program doesn't wait for the player to choose and instead it crash because it doesn't have value

So I searcher about threads, tried for a long time can't achieve to figure out how it works
I did some tests (bellow) that my archly resemble what I need to do with my code
But it doesn't work neither
Do someone have an answer ?

````
import threading
import tkinter as tk

windo = tk.Tk()
windo.title("Morpion")
windo.resizable(width=tk.FALSE, height=tk.FALSE)

class Player:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.choice = None

def Change_Var(x):
    print(P.choice)
    P.choice = x
    print(P.choice)
    play_event.set()

def boucle():
    i = 0
    while not play_event.isSet() and i < 3000:
        print(i)
        i += 1

P = Player("Deltix")
start = tk.Button(height=2,width=8, text = "Start",command = lambda x = 0 : Change_Var(x))
start.grid(column = 2, row = 3,pady = 5)

play_event = threading.Event()
threading.Thread(target = windo.mainloop()).start
threading.Thread(target = boucle()).start```
````

Comment: You need to work through a tutorial on responding to a button click.

Comment: ***`target = boucle()`***: Read [why-is-button-parameter-command-executed-when-declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228) and [Tkinter understanding mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29158947/7414759)

Comment: You definitely don't need threads for this.

Comment: Are you aware of events in tkinter? You can bind a key to any event in tkinter. Threads aren't needed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use threads, just use events.

Say you wanted to bind a function to the enter key.

This would be your code:

```py
canvas = Canvas(master)
def clicked(event):
    print("Enter was pressed")
canvas.bind("<Return>", clicked)
```

You can read more about tkinter events [here](https://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_events_binds.php).

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: It really helps I think
I am now searching about this but 
I tried event.isSet() with the "<Return>" and it doesn't work (obviously) but is there an equivalent ? 

I need to make my program stop until someone click a button and I didn't find anything about this anywhere

Comment: I also found about update() instead of mainloop() and I thinks it's a big leap forward but there is still a problem about "waiting" for the user

Comment: You don't need to use event.isSet(). Just use the bind function like listed above. If you need a bigger example I will edit my answer.

Comment: I'd like please,
I think I already understand how bind and the event works but I need a way to "stop a function until an event" instead of "starting when there is one" like in your example